# Dates with spring data

Tags: spring, spring-data

I have two dates as parameters, and I need all records between those dates.  My problem is that my query doesn't work, because is retrieving a empty list. This is my query:

```
@Query("select ta from TravelerAdventureEntity ta  WHERE ta.fromDate <= :from and ta.toDate >= :to and ta.saveAndShare =1")
public List<TravelerAdventureEntity> findTravelersByDate(@Param("from") Date from,@Param("to") Date to,Pageable page);
```

Does anybody know how dates work in spring data? 
Thank you.

Comment: You might avoid such typos if you switch to `between :from and :to`.

Answer (score 2):

fromDate should be the beginning and toDate the end, right ?
No offense, but I think you are tired or something :)

```
@Query("select ta from TravelerAdventureEntity ta  WHERE ta.fromDate >= :from and ta.toDate <= :to and ta.saveAndShare =1")
public List<TravelerAdventureEntity> findTravelersByDate(@Param("from") Date from,@Param("to") Date to,Pageable page);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right!,  I have changed toDate and from, before post my answer. In the begining was ok. thank you anyway. 
I have just found my error, and it was in the parameter page, I was looking for in a page without results.